# Retrieving latest version of content item with related records immediately after creating it

Tags: orchardcms

I'm building a module where the data has a parent child relationship. I've created a service with a method to create new parent records along with their children. The method looks something like this:

```
public ParentPart CreateParent(...)
  // Create parent content item
  var parentPart = _contentManager.New("Parent").As<ParentPart>();
  parentPart.PropertyA = "value...";
  _contentManager.Create(parentPart);

  // Create child
  var childRecord = new ChildRecord { 
    ChildPropertyA = "value...",
    ParentPartRecord = parentPart.Record
  };
  _childRepository.Create(childRecord);

  // Re-fetch parent part to try and get related child records
  return _contentManager.Get(parentPart.Id).As<ParentPart>();
}
```

Here's what the part and record classes look like:

```
public class ParentPart : ContentPart<ParentPartRecord> {
  public string PropertyA {
    get { return Retrieve(r => r.PropertyA); }
    set { return Store(r => r.PropertyA, value); }
  }

  public IEnumerable<ChildRecord> Children{
     get {
       return Record.Children;
     }
  }
}

public class ParentPartRecord : ContentPartRecord {
  public virtual string PropertyA { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<ChildRecord> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildRecord {
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string ChildPropertyA { get; set; }
  public virtual ParentPartRecord ParentPartRecord { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, after calling the CreateParent method of my service, the returned ParentPart's Children collection is null. I'm pretty sure the relationship is setup correctly since on any subsequent request, I can retrieve the content item and access the child records just fine.

It seems like content item's record is not updating until sometime after I'm requesting the children. Is there a way to force this so I can retrieve the children immediately after calling this method without waiting for the next request?

Comment: I found that calling ITransactionManager.RequireNew() before re-fetching the content items does indeed return a ParentPart with the children populated. I'd be interested to know if others think this is an appropriate solution or if it may have unintended side effects.

Comment: Can you explain what the specific scenario is? There are few cases where this is necessary.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy  I've added examples of the part and record classes for context. They are simplifications of my actual code but exhibit the same problem. It really boils down to the fact that immediately after calling CreateParent on my service, the Children property of ParentPart is null. However, when I check it on the next request, it has the ChildRecord I would expect. Calling ITransactionManager.RequireNew() before re-fetching the ParentPart (last line of CreateParent method) seems to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm glad you could make it work, but that's not what I was asking. The question is still about super-abstract "child" and "parent" parts. I'm wondering why you aren't using one of the many other ways you can establish parent-child relationships, such as content picker field, taxonomies, or lists?

Comment: Oh, I totally misread your question. My actual classes are not called parent and child (those were just examples for illustration) or intended to be used anywhere except this very specific case inside my custom module. The actual classes are modeling a very specific type of request (parent) that has multiple line items (children) on it. Similar to the line items that may appear on a purchase order. In fact, I thought about using your Nwazet.Commerce module but there were too many details for my case that just didn't fit a typical purchase order.

Comment: Well, then you might want to consider a simpler approach than records and relationships, such as storing the collection of children into the infoset of the parent, unless you're already done.

Comment: You're probably right that it would have been easier to serialize the children into the parent infoset. I am mostly done and it seems to work fine. Do you see any potential issues or side effects with what I'm doing though? Or is it just not the way you would have done it?

Comment: Depends on your scenario, really. I have an ongoing series of blog posts the pros and cons of various ways to build relationships in Orchard.